# Use Apache Felix iPOJO Event Admin Handlers

Tags: java, event-handling, osgi, apache-felix, ipojo

I want to use [Event Admin Handlers](http://felix.apache.org/site/event-admin-handlers.html).

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.event.Publishes;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.event.Subscriber;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.handlers.event.publisher.Publisher;
...
@Component(immediate = true, publicFactory = false)
@Provides(specifications = {Test.class})
@Instantiate
public class Test {
...
    @Publishes(name = "myPublisher", topics = "foo")
    private Publisher m_publisher;
...
    @Subscriber(name = "mySubscriber", topics = "foo")
    public void receive(Event pEvent) {
    ...
    }
}
```

But have error:

```
! instances
...
Instance test.Test-0 -> invalid
...

! instance test.Test-0
gogo: NullPointerException: null
```

As I understand it, can not get Instance of Publisher component. I have active "Apache Felix iPOJO Event Admin Handler (1.8.0)" bundle.

Use:

- Apache Felix 4.2.1
- org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations (1.11.0)
- org.apache.felix.ipojo.api (1.11.0)
- org.apache.felix.ipojo.handler.eventadmin (1.8.0)

What is wrong? Thx.

---

This is bundle list:

```
! lb
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (4.2.1)
    1|Active     |    1|Commons Codec (1.8.0)
    4|Active     |    1|Commons IO (2.4.0)
    5|Active     |    1|Commons Lang (2.6.0)
    6|Active     |    1|Commons Lang (3.1.0)
    7|Active     |    1|jcl-over-slf4j (1.7.5)
   10|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.6)
   12|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0)
   13|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
   14|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
   15|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO (1.11.0)
   16|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO API (1.11.0)
   17|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO Gogo Command (1.11.0)
   18|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO Event Admin Handler (1.8.0)
   19|Active     |    1|osgi.cmpn (4.2.0.200908310645)
   20|Active     |    1|slf4j-api (1.7.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the NPE happening when collecting the architecture of your instance is a bug. Could you raise an issue on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX

Then, it seems that you didn't deploy the event admin. You can download it from http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi.

Clement

Comment: But the Instance which contain @Subscriber throws "gogo: NullPointerException: null" after creation.